# Unique url for a wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, google-news

I run a wordpress blog..
And I'm considering submitting by blog to Google News, now Google says each of your websites page's needs to have a unique url with atleast 3 numbers.

how should I get this done? Is there a particular wordpress plugin that'll do the job?

Regards,

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? Google shouldn't be mandating that your URL have numbers in it.

Comment: Try asking this question on the wordpress.org forums.  I think you'll probably get a better answer since this question isn't really programming related.

Answer (score 3):

[You do not need a numeric ID in your URL if you use a news sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/news/thread?tid=61f0fdb58009299d&hl=en). [Here's a plugin for automatically generating one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-news-sitemap-generator/).